# Check for a regex string match in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm writing some client-side validation for our custom CMS. I need to check for any URL containing an image in a text area, and let the user know that they need to use https instead of http.

I've figured out how to search for any URL that starts with http:

```
$('#template_form').submit(function() {
        val = $("#template_data").val();
        if (val.match(/http:\/\//)) {
            alert("You must set all complete image URLs to be https!");
            $("#logError").val("true");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

But this will also apply to any regular links that are included. If we could limit this to `<img>` tags it would be simpler, because I could just get the last three characters of the string and do an `indexOf` against an array of image suffixes.

We can't do that, though - an image URL could be included in a custom tag, it could be part of an `alt` parameter, it could be posted as a direct link, or any number of other things. Is there any way to test the regex against an array, or do I need to loop through the array and run a `String.indexOf` against each element separately?

Ideally, I'd do something like this:

```
suffixes = [".jpg", ",jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".tiff", ".bmp"];
if (val.match(/http:\/\//)) && suffixes.indexOf(**some kind of regex**) {
    alert("You must set all complete image URLs to be https!");
    $("#logError").val("true");
    return false;
}
```

but I can't quite figure out what that regex would be.

Comment: Is `val` just html?

Comment: @KevBot - yes, although some of it is custom tags.

Comment: suffix regex:  /\.(jpe?g|png|bmp|tiff|gif)/g;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a regex using your image extensions:

```
var suffixes = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "tiff", "bmp"];

var re = new RegExp('http://[^>\\s]+?\.(?:' + suffixes.join('|') + ')');

if (re.test(val)) {
    alert("You must set all complete image URLs to be https!");
    $("#logError").val("true");
    return false;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qo7gs34c/3/)

**Code Demo**

```js
var val = '<img src="http://www.google.com/test.jpg" />';
var suffixes = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "tiff", "bmp"];
var re = new RegExp('http://[^>\\s]+?\.(?:' + suffixes.join('|') + ')');

console.log(re.test(val));
```

Comment: `.*` is a bit aggresive use a url regex instead

Comment: Hm. That sounds like what I want, but I must be implementing it incorrectly. I'm updating the OP with what I did; please help!

Comment: It prints exactly what I showed in the OP as the text I typed into the textarea:

all image urls must be secure

this is not an image url: http://www.google.com

this is `<img src="http://www.google.com/test.jpg" />`

Comment: (Sorry, can't figure out how to format multiple lines in a comment.)

Comment: That returns true for the URL you entered. It needs to return false - it contains an image suffix and *doesn't* start with https.

Comment: That still doesn't work if there's more than one URL in the text. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EmmyS/qo7gs34c/1/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129463/discussion-between-anubhava-and-emmys).